# String can't be cast to an Integer and Integer can't be cast to a String

Tags: java, classcastexception

The `getHttpPort` method returns an `Object` type derived from a JSON data query. The value of the `Object` could be a blank string or an Integer value. To be on the safe side I thought I could represent it as a String like this:

```
String port = (String)getHttpPort(param);
```

But this sometimes generates the error:

```
Integer cannot be cast to a String.
```

So I tried this:

```
String port = ((Integer)getHttpPort(param).toString();
```

But now I get the reverse error:

```
String cannot be cast to an Integer.
```

What's the proper way to represent the returned result of the `getHttpPort` method as a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

`String port = getHttpPort(param).toString();`

?

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` is present in every class in Java. So change this

```
String port = ((Integer)getHttpPort(param).toString();
```

to

```
String port = getHttpPort(param).toString();
```

Now, this will work for the scenarios where toString() is implemented .